# Dynamic SYSLINUX menu?

Tags: linux, isolinux

Is it possible to have a menu in SYSLINUX that will automatically list all of the files in a given directory and allow the user to choose one to boot from as a kernel?

Answer (score 2):

With the last versions of Syslinux (4.xx), you have an ls.c32 module with which you can list a directory.
You still need to enter the commandline for booting your kernel yourself.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to write a script, which you could run manually or could be set to run automatically (perhaps at shutdown), which looks through the directory and rebuilds the syslinux config file for you. This gives you more control to specify exactly what arguments, etc. might be needed, and to have some default options that show up regardless of the contents of the directory.